# The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden - Web Deploy

Tags: c#, asp.net, msdeploy, webdeploy

I am getting an error "Could not connect to the remote computer using the specified process ("Web management Service") because the server did not respond. Make sure that the process ("Web management Service") is started on the remote computer. The remote server returned an error : (403) Forbidden.

- Made sure Web Management Service is started and set to Automatic
- Made sure that Web Deployment Agent Service is started and set to
  Automatic
- Web Deploy 3.5 is installed
- Enabled remote connections in Management Service With `Windows
  Credentials or IIS Manager credentials`
- Enabled 8172 port using Windows Firewall with Advanced Security

But when using the connection with http://servername in Visual Studio, it is able to connect but using only servername in server its not able to connect giving the above error.

My question is why it works differently when using Visual Studio and when using MSDeploy Command Line I am getting an error like Could not complete the request to remote agent URL 'http://servername:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=MySite'.
Error: The operation has timed out

The Error in Log File is

sc-status : 403, sc-substatus : 503, sc-win32-status : 5, time-taken : 1265

Answer (score 1):

The problem for me was that when webdeploy was installed, "typical" was selected instead of "complete". But I didn't modify the install, just uninstall it and then reinstalled it. Because modifying it led to another issue.

Answer (score 0):

from memory it seems you did everything correct, but 403 means that you did not get authorised. you said only servername, so i am assuming that you are trying without a username and password (anonymous) but im not sure that will work.

personally i have a local admin user on the server that i am deploying to, and i use that username and password when publishing from visual studio.

below is an example image of the connection page when creating a publish profile. validate connection button should give a green check mark next to it if everything is correct, and a warning symbol and a link to the problem if not.

[image]